# .append is executed more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.append` is executed more than once (3 times) even though function only calls it once.

```
$('#container, #tree').on('click', 'li', function(event){
        $( '#myAreaDiv' ).append( FIELD:<br /><input name="myField" id="myField" readonly value="2"/>' );

        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Please redact your question correctly so it would be useful in future to other users.

Comment: I see that you are new to stack overflow. Can you provide us with more information? JSFiddle would also be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, because I think your FIELD is not right.
Click on Tree...

```js
$('#container, #tree').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
  $('#myAreaDiv').append('<br /> <input name="myField" id ="myField" readonly value="2"/>');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tree">
  <li>
    Tree
  </li>
</div>

<div id="myAreaDiv">

</div>
```